# Code copied straight from java book doesn't want to run

Tags: java, user-interface

Can someone tell me why this doesnt run?? I've copied this straight from my introduction to java book.. When running it is supposed return a window displaying six figures.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFigurePanel extends JFrame {
  public TestFigurePanel() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 5, 5));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.LINE));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.RECTANGLE));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.ROUND_RECTANGLE));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.OVAL));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.RECTANGLE, true));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.ROUND_RECTANGLE, true));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestFigurePanel frame = new TestFigurePanel();
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setTitle("TestFigurePanel");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having, specifically?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (FigurePanel)
 FigurePanel cannot be resolved to a type
 FigurePanel cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: So, what *is* a `FigurePanel`?  A quick search indicates it's from some Intro to Programming course in NYC.

Comment: Put that in your question, please. Also, could you add some detail about what you want it to do?

Comment: `FigurePanel` must not extend a `JComponent`. It is unclear why `TestFigurePanel` does.

Comment: When it runs its supposed to give me a window with some differnt rectangles etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you copied relies on other code—specifically, the code for `FigurePanel`. You will need to find that and include that other code (and anything that it depends on) in your project before you can compile and run the code you posted.

Comment: I had to turn a few pages to find the remaining code. Been sitting here scratching my head. Thank you!

Comment: @AndréHatlo-Johansen - Well, I can't help you with your book, but perhaps [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120641/cant-get-netbeans-to-access-figurepanel-in-java) might help. Judging from a quick web search I just did, it seems that `FigurePanel` is a pretty popular Java class used in Java programming courses.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public class TestFigurePanel1 extends JFrame {
    public TestFigurePane1l() {
    ...
```

by

```
 public class TestFigurePanel extends JFrame {
      public TestFigurePanel() {
      ....
```